# Minecraft: PE on Kindle cannot connect to another Kindle running Minecraft: PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

We have two Kindles that both have Minecraft: Pocket Edition on them.

When we try to join games and play together only 1 of the Kindles shows a list of Wi-Fi games active. Why doesn't the other Kindle show the same list and read the other Kindle's active games? Whenever we want to join it's only one sided every time. Kindle 1 can join Kindle 2 but Kindle 2 cannot join Kindle 1.

Is there a setting I can change so both can join either game?

Comment: Normally I'd suggest checking that both devices are on the same wifi network, but that already seems to be the case.

Comment: Yea,on the same network so not sure why we can't see both??

Comment: Did you try a direct connect?

Comment: @YoungGuilo What is a "direct connect"? Does the Kindle Fire sport an Ethernet port?

Comment: Multiplayer worlds show up at the bottom of your worlds list. Can you confirm that you're scrolling all the way to the bottom and still not finding the server?

Answer (score 3):

On one kindle start the world you both want to play on. Then with the second kindle goto multiplayer and click the wifi game. You will then join the game that is on the first kindle.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be in the same room and wifi has to be on both and have to have the same computer or it won't work